# place a curly brace block into gradle file

Tags: awk, curly-braces

I have a snippet of build.gradle file like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.softtech.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

I need to place the following block into above gradle snippet (in jenkins execute shell)

```
myConfig{
    debug{
        myFile = file("/Users/john/a/b/c/d/x.file")
    }
}
```

like the following:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.softtech.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    *myConfig{
        debug{
            myFile = file("/Users/user1/a/b/c/d/x.file")
        }
    }*
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

I'm rusted as I have not used advanced AWK for a long time, I appreciate your help doesnt matter its awk or sed or perl

Tried to use RS as "}\nbuild" and print fields but didnt work

thanks

Comment: Is there no tool for editing "gradle" files that understands that language? Like there's `jq` for JSON, `yq` for YAML, etc.?

Comment: There must be, looking for it this is a dirty workaround. In the gradle file a signing part missing actually which has to be put there and commited to git and I dont have accessibility there to change thats why looked for a workaround. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
NR==FNR { rec = (NR>2 ? rec ORS : "") $0; next }
$1 == "buildTypes" {
    indent = $0
    sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",indent)
    gsub(/\n/,"&"indent,rec)
    print indent rec
}
{ print }
' <( printf '
myConfig{
    debug{
        myFile = file("/Users/john/a/b/c/d/x.file")
    }
}
' ) "$1"
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh file.gradle
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.softtech.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    myConfig{
        debug{
            myFile = file("/Users/john/a/b/c/d/x.file")
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ed thanks a lot really it was such a tedious job to create for me. Im amazed that you even thought about indent and set it before actual manipulation. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU sed:

Create a text file called replace.txt with the proper spacing

```
    myConfig{
        debug{
            myFile = file("/Users/john/a/b/c/d/x.file")
        }
    }
```

Use sed to insert the text above "buildTypes"

```
sed -i "/buildTypes/e cat replace.txt" file.txt
```

(In future, please include the code from your own attempts to solve the problem with your question)

Comment: I used the command but failed. Sed -i is not supported but i tried the alternative like the following: `| => uname
Darwin
| => sed -i "/buildTypes/e cat replace.txt" file.txt
sed: 1: "file.txt": invalid command code f
| => sed "/buildTypes/e cat replace.txt" file.txt > file.tmp && mv file.tmp > file.txt
sed: 1: "/buildTypes/e cat repla ...": invalid command code e`

Comment: Yep, this command requires GNU sed. It won't work with BSD sed ('macos' sed)